# CCK Migrate filefield to file error

Tags: 6, migrations, entities

I tried using CCK Migrate and this happens and field fails to get migrated, can someone let me know how to read this kind of error:

```
Requesting rollback of field "field_evt_mat_download" due to failure to convert record:

array ( 'entity_id' => '4715', 'revision_id' => '4742', 'field_evt_mat_download_fid' => '9109', 'field_evt_mat_download_data' => 'a:1:{s:11:"description";s:32:"Presentation (Open as Read Only)";}', 'delta' => '8', 'entity_type' => 'node', 'language' => 'und', 'bundle' => 'event', 'field_evt_mat_download_description' => 'Presentation (Open as Read Only)', 'field_evt_mat_download_display' => '1', )

Cause:

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'public://local marketing/event/member-appreciation-october/2012/' for key 'uri'' in D:\xampp\htdocs\aadev\dev7\includes\database\database.inc:2171 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\aadev\dev7\includes\database\database.inc(2171): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured out that the `field_evt_mat_download` is actually in `field_data_field_evt_mat_download` so I solved the problem myself.